The product of Jacobian determinants
I wonder if the following proposition holds:
$\def\vb{\boldsymbol}$
$\def\pdv#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$

Suppose $D,G\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, function $\vb{T}\colon D \to G,(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n)\mapsto(y_1,y_2,\dotsc,y_n)$ is $C^1$ diffeomorphic, then$$
 \begin{vmatrix}
  \pdv{y_1}{x_1} & \pdv{y_1}{x_2} & \dots & \pdv{y_1}{x_n} \\
  \pdv{y_2}{x_1} & \pdv{y_2}{x_2} & \dots & \pdv{y_2}{x_n} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
  \pdv{y_n}{x_1} & \pdv{y_n}{x_2} & \dots & \pdv{y_n}{x_n} \\
 \end{vmatrix}
 \begin{vmatrix}
  \pdv{x_1}{y_1} & \pdv{x_1}{y_2} & \dots & \pdv{x_1}{y_n} \\
  \pdv{x_2}{y_1} & \pdv{x_2}{y_2} & \dots & \pdv{x_2}{y_n} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
  \pdv{x_n}{y_1} & \pdv{x_n}{y_2} & \dots & \pdv{x_n}{y_n} \\
 \end{vmatrix}
 = 1.
$$

So far I deduced that \begin{align*}
 &\begin{vmatrix}
  \pdv{y_1}{x_1} & \pdv{y_1}{x_2} & \dots & \pdv{y_1}{x_n} \\
  \pdv{y_2}{x_1} & \pdv{y_2}{x_2} & \dots & \pdv{y_2}{x_n} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
  \pdv{y_n}{x_1} & \pdv{y_n}{x_2} & \dots & \pdv{y_n}{x_n} \\
 \end{vmatrix}
 \begin{vmatrix}
  \pdv{x_1}{y_1} & \pdv{x_1}{y_2} & \dots & \pdv{x_1}{y_n} \\
  \pdv{x_2}{y_1} & \pdv{x_2}{y_2} & \dots & \pdv{x_2}{y_n} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
  \pdv{x_n}{y_1} & \pdv{x_n}{y_2} & \dots & \pdv{x_n}{y_n} \\
 \end{vmatrix} \\
 &= \det\left(
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \pdv{y_1}{x_1} & \pdv{y_1}{x_2} & \dots & \pdv{y_1}{x_n} \\
   \pdv{y_2}{x_1} & \pdv{y_2}{x_2} & \dots & \pdv{y_2}{x_n} \\
   \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
   \pdv{y_n}{x_1} & \pdv{y_n}{x_2} & \dots & \pdv{y_n}{x_n} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \pdv{x_1}{y_1} & \pdv{x_1}{y_2} & \dots & \pdv{x_1}{y_n} \\
   \pdv{x_2}{y_1} & \pdv{x_2}{y_2} & \dots & \pdv{x_2}{y_n} \\
   \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
   \pdv{x_n}{y_1} & \pdv{x_n}{y_2} & \dots & \pdv{x_n}{y_n} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
 \right) \\
 &= \begin{vmatrix}
  \sum_{k=1}^n \pdv{y_1}{x_k} \pdv{x_k}{y_1}
  & \sum_{k=1}^n \pdv{y_1}{x_k} \pdv{x_k}{y_2}
  & \dots
  & \sum_{k=1}^n \pdv{y_1}{x_k} \pdv{x_k}{y_n} \\
  \sum_{k=1}^n \pdv{y_2}{x_k} \pdv{x_k}{y_1}
  & \sum_{k=1}^n \pdv{y_2}{x_k} \pdv{x_k}{y_2}
  & \dots
  & \sum_{k=1}^n \pdv{y_2}{x_k} \pdv{x_k}{y_n} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
  \sum_{k=1}^n \pdv{y_n}{x_k} \pdv{x_k}{y_1}
  & \sum_{k=1}^n \pdv{y_n}{x_k} \pdv{x_k}{y_2}
  & \dots
  & \sum_{k=1}^n \pdv{y_n}{x_k} \pdv{x_k}{y_n} \\
 \end{vmatrix}.
\end{align*}
I've no idea what to do next because it's not possible to eliminate partial derivatives like
$$
\pdv{y_i}{x_j} \pdv{x_j}{y_i} = 1.
$$

Have you considered what this looks like from the perspective of the chain rule?
$\frac{dx}{dx}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial y_1}\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial y_2}\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x}+..$

Partial derivatives can't cancel like that. You can interpret this as evidence that partial derivatives are not fractions, or that $\partial x_j$ actually hides some information, so it's not the same object on the numerator and denominator.

$$\begin{align*}\mathrm{d}y_i=&\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}\mathrm{d}x_j\\=&\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial y_l}\mathrm{d}y_l\end{align*}$$
Thus
$$\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial y_l}=\mathrm{\delta}_{il}$$
